# View full message headers on Outlook 2011 for Mac

Tags: macos, email, headers, office-for-mac, microsoft-outlook-2011

How can I view the full headers of a message with Outlook 2011 for Mac?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The only way I've found is to right-click on the message in the message list and choose **View Source** in the popup menu. This will open the full source of the message, including headers, in a new TextEdit document.

Comment: +1. Just to clarify, you have to right-click on the message on the message in the *list* of messages, not the body of the message or the message opened in a separate window.

Answer (score 1):

Just `Save as` the email to disk, and open it with a text editor.

Answer (score -2):

On any Mac, holding down the Control key and clicking is the equivalent of right-clicking on a PC. It will usually bring up a contextual menu that shows choices of actions available for the element that is selected at the time.

To see which e-mail address an e-mail was sent to, open the specific e-mail, then hover over the alias in the e-mail header's To field. A pop-up will expand to show the actual e-mail address tied to that alias.

Seeing the full e-mail address of the sender is a little more complicated, because hovering over the From alias usually displays only a truncated portion of the actual e-mail address. The same can happen if you hit Reply (with the intention of deleting the Reply e-mail before sending it).

However, if you hover over the From address, a pop-up window will appear, with a number of icons along the bottom. The icon all the way on the right (picture of an index card) will open an Outlook Contact form, where the full e-mail address of the Sender will be displayed. Once you've viewed the e-mail address, close the Contact form and choose Don't Save (unless you really want to create a contact for that sender, in which case, hit Save). Sounds complicated, but only takes a few seconds.

Comment: Interesting, but it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: "A pop-up will expand to show the actual e-mail address tied to that alias." — That doesn't work on the current version of Outlook for Mac.